# Create APFS RAM disk on macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, terminal, apfs

usually creating RAM disks works with the following commands

```
hdid -nomount ram://<blocksize>
```

Returns e.g. /dev/disk2
Then I would format the disk, with say

```
newfs_hfs /dev/disk2
```

followed by mounting it:

```
mount -t hfs /dev/disk2 /some/mount/target
```

This procedure doesn't seem to work with APFS. I'm on High Sierra beta 9. The mount command doesn't output any error, but the path is not mounted.

In my case, after the `hdid` command finished, `newfs_apfs -i /dev/disk2` yields

```
nx_kernel_mount:1364: checkpoint search: largest xid 1, best xid 1 @ 1
nx_kernel_mount:1422: sanity checking all nx state... please be patient.
spaceman_metazone_init:278: no metazone for device 0, of size 209715200 bytes, block_size 4096
apfs_newfs:18075: FS will NOT be encrypted.
```

When I then enter `mount -t apfs /dev/disk2 /some/target/path` then the mount commands seems to work for 2 seconds, doesn't give any output and the mount was NOT succesful.

Can anyone tell me how to actually make a APFS RAM disk s.t. it works? :p

PS: I've also tried something like `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk2 GPT APFS myvolumename 0b` which does mount the volume to `/Volumes/myvolumename` but creates yet another disk (`disk3` in this case) which seems odd to me!

Comment: `disk3` in this case is a Core Storage container, which is more or less a required component of APFS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Storage

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
hdid -nomount ram://<blocksize>
diskutil erasedisk <format> <diskname> <output path of previous hdid command>
```

where `<format>` is taken from `diskutil listFilesystems` from the "Personality" column. Yes, it seems weird to me too that you may have to quote this parameter, e.g. when specifying case-sensitive variants, but oh well...

`<blocksize>` is 2048 * `desired size in megabytes`

The last command formats the RAM disk and mounts it to `/Volumes/<diskname>`

It seems to be the case that when now entering `diskutil list` that you will see **two** new disks, the one `hdid` created, and a synthesized one.

To **destroy** the RAM disk again, call `diskutil eject <output path of previous hdid command>`, e.g. `diskutil eject /dev/disk2`

This will do all the work for you, unmounting the `/Volumes/<diskname>` path and destroy the two disks, releasing your memory.

Keep in mind that the minimum/maximum values for `<blocksize>` depend on the chosen `<format>`. Also, `<diskname>` cannot always be chosen arbitrarily. Exemplary, FAT32 requires it to consist of upper-case letters!

Cheers!

Comment: Following these instructions (albeit using `hdiutil attach` rather than `hdid` since `hdid` is deprecated) I always get `Mounting disk
Could not mount disk2 after erase` , whereas the same command line with `HFS+` instead of `APFS` results in success.  What are the acceptable minimum/maximum values for APFS volumes?

Comment: `diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://2097152) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'APFS RAM Disk' '100%'` worked for me though :)

Answer (score 32):

@Glyph provided the best answer in a comment to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46272951/5088075), but it deserves its own answer:

```
diskutil partitionDisk $(hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((2048*sizeInMB))) 1 GPTFormat APFS 'Ramdisk' '100%'
```

Change `sizeInMB` to your desired size.

*I've updated Glyph's answer to simplify the volume name a little.*

Comment: Would love a way to sync this with a folder on the ssd! Starting the sync will 1. Do the initial load of the folder on ssd into the ramdisk, 2. Sync changes from ramdisk to ssd. Two additional nice features would be 3. Help you open the ramdisk folder with your program of choice, once it's copied over; and 4. Prevent programs from changing the folder on the ssd/or at least warn when that happens. @Glyph

Comment: Does this not delete some of my data? Disk "1" does not exist. How do I know what disk to pick?

Answer (score 0):

Also, info to delete/destroy the RAM disk needs to be corrected. ramdisk will be created at path /Volumes/'ramdisk', so the command is:

```
diskutil eject /Volumes/'ramdisk'
```